# GPO - Schedule Backup from users Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy, windows-10, task

Im Using Robocopy to copy files from my users Desktop to their Personally folder on the Server..

im using robocopy C:\Users\%username%\Desktop W:\skrivebord /xo /fft /E
which works perfectly, when its running from the desktop or via local Scheduled task.

However, if i create this Scheduled task via GPO, the user is "system"

I can change the user, but this needs to according to the user himself, and not a predefined user in the script.

How can i make a task, which is used by every user on the GPO?

Answer (score 1):

The robocopy parameters indicates that you are synchronizing files. It won't be that simple if you want to use just robocopy and Task Scheduler. You can create PowerShell script to check which user is currently logged on, and create copy of files using robocopy. You can also deploy [Folder Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275(v=ws.11).aspx) to handle that in completely other way. This solution have pros and cons of course.

Comment: Hi Mrc, I solved it with greating a Task for Vista and later - By this method, i could choose %loggedin% - Thanks.